# Lucee 5.3.3.62 - Error - Cannot open database "penumbra" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, lucee

Bit of background, I need to remake this ColdFusion app in C# so I set up the legacy project on my machine and it was working fine till today, when I messed up running SQL commands (I know I should have used transactions, hindsight is fantastic). So I had a backup I made yesterday so I just deleted the DB I had in my SQLExpress and restored the backup and then I encoutnered the error below.

I don't remember making any changes or setting up anything in the permissions for the database so I don't think it something related to that.

I am getting the below error message when trying to login to the CF app that is running on Lucee, on my local machine.

> Message    Cannot open database "appName" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:555eb338-984e-4edf-a12b-c0662a0f6068
> Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
> C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\appName\admin_cfcs\login.cfc: line 69
> called from C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\appName\admin\authenticate.cfm: line 26
> called from C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\appName\admin\dashboard\dashboard.cfm: line 2

Comment: Check the logs on the SQL Server, which will give the true connection error. If you then don't understand that error, post that error in your question as an [edit].

Comment: Found the error in the Logs as suggested I had setup a user, for the database and it wasn't assigned to the database when I restored the new copy, so I just had to add the database "appName" to the User Mapping. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer thanks to @Larnu 's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803533/lucee-5-3-3-62-error-cannot-open-database-penumbra-requested-by-the-login#comment114575639_64803533) in a comment to the questions.

Found the error in the Logs as suggested I had setup a user, for the database and it wasn't assigned to the database when I restored the new copy, so I just had to add the database "appName" to the User Mapping. Thanks :)